# Importing pyplot causes Inconsistency/Exception

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, shared-libraries, anaconda

I have just updated my Anaconda environment on a 64 bit Linux server running Debian. I am now using version `2.1.2` of `matplotlib`. Now, whenever I want to import `pyplot` on `python`, `python` terminates and I get this error message:

```
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  3 2017, 20:01:27)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
readline: /etc/inputrc: line 18: term: unknown variable name
readline: /etc/inputrc: line 18: term: unknown variable name
>>> import matplotlib
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 583: _dl_open: Assertion `_dl_debug_initialize (0, args.nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!
```

Apparently there is some mix up in the libraries - but I do not really know how to get more information/solve this issue. What shall I do now?

**Edit**: I was able to narrow down the source of this exception to the `Qt` interface of `pyplot`. When I force `matplotlib` to use `pdf` or `Agg` as the renderer, this error does not occur.